# Connect to AWS Neptune Having IAM Auth from Local Machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, amazon-neptune

I am trying to connect to a Neptune cluster which is enabled with IAM authentication.

To connect to the cluster I have configured an ALB and EC2 instance to forward the request from local machine to the Neptune cluster.

1. ALB is setup to accept inbound traffic from my IP address and targets it to an EC2 instance.
2. The EC2 instance is in the VPC where Neptune cluster is running which accepts traffic from the ALB.
3. Reverse nginx proxy is configured in EC2 instance to redirect the request to Neptune writer endpoint.

This is setup is working when Neptune does not have IAM authentication. But When the authentication is enabled I am getting 403 response from the Neptune cluster.
`"code": "AccessDeniedException"`

For authentication I am sending all the headers that are required by Neptune.
`Authorization`, `X-Amz-Date` and `X-Amz-Security-Token`

I am using Gremlin .Net client to establish the connection using this URI `ws://{ALB_IP_ADDRESS}:{ALB_PORT}`.

If I use `wss` scheme then I get `The SSL connection could not be established` error.

And the reverse proxy configuration looks like this.

```
server {
    listen 8081;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://cluster-name.cluster-xyzabc.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host cluster-name.cluster-xyzabc.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_buffers           32 4m;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size     25m;
        proxy_buffer_size 512k;
        proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires";
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size        1024m;
        client_body_buffer_size     4m;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;
        proxy_intercept_errors off;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    }
 }
```

What am I missing here? It seems like some issue with headers that are not getting forwarded to Neptune cluster from the proxy.

The code to create Gremlin client is working when it is deployed in the Cloud but from local it is returning me 403 response.

Comment: Does the [material here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dbs-refarch-graph/tree/master/src/connecting-using-a-load-balancer) help? In particular make sure you are using the actual Neptune Cluster DNS to sign the request and not that of the ALB. Also, take note of the different ways that an ALB, versus an NLB, will handle the Host headers.

Comment: Are you able to log a request from the reverse proxy to Neptune so that you can inspect the headers? We may be able to better diagnose if we can see a full request from the proxy. Thanks.